# Control over who can use audio output channel in XP

Tags: c#, audio, windows-xp

I have a need to turn off other audio sources when I plan to use the Text to Speech API. The other audio may be in another process. I have looked at the mixer control, but I really only have control of the output there. Is there another place in XP that I can control the output so only my app is able to be heard?

Answer (score 1):

See http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx